# How to retrieve stream name by a given view name in ClearCase UCM?

Tags: view, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the stream which a given view is belong to.
When  I use "ClearCase Explorer" and right-click for view's properties, I get its stream name, but I can't find how to retrieve that with scripts. The stream information does not appear on view .vws files nor registry.

I know I can do some manipulation to get it from view's config-spec, but I'm still looking for the easiest way to find it our.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By script:

```
cleartool lsstream -view view_tag
```

See [`cleartool lsstream` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm):

```
–vie/w view-tag
```

> Displays information for the stream connected to the specified view.