# Issue in checking out a file after cleartool startview command

Tags: unix, clearcase, cleartool

I want to checkout a Clearcase file through unix command using **cleartool co** but I ended up seeing the following error message.

**cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view.**

I ran **cleartool startview myview** and **cleartool setactivity myactivity** and then I am trying to checkout a file.

Is file **check out** and **check in** commands tagged to setview instead of startview?

I am using startview command after going thru the following post [Do not use setview instead use startview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188)

Answer (score 0):

As explained before ([in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188/6309)), do not use `cleartool setview`

You just need to make sure that `myview` is indeed an UCM view (meaning [lsstream is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7872583/6309))

```
cd /path/to/view
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

Also, do the `cleartool setact` inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to list down the steps to get the solution working.

1) Created new view (myview) for a dynamic view/Integration View.

2) Navigate to the view folder which will be like homedirofserver/view/myview.

3) Created a new activity say myActivity(My initial problem was working with an activity which was previously set to another view.

4) set myActivity to myview and received message **set activity 'myActivity' in view 'myview'**

5) Then Navigated down to my scripts folder which is under homedirofserver/view/myview/vobs/vobname/myapp/WEB-INF

6) Ran scripts to checkout the scripts file.

It worked!!