# How to retrieve the integration-stream that belongs to my development view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a development view, which is linked to a development stream, which delivers to an integration stream.

What is the best way to find the integration stream using console commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`fmt_ccase` query](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) with [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm), by looking at the UCM *project*:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[istream]Xp" project:myProject@\myPVob
```

If you don't have the project name ready, you can:

- [get the stream from your view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35937436/6309)
- [list all pvobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36028214/6309) and find the one which includes said dev stream: the current project will be your project name, from which you can get the integration stream name.

Comment: I love asking questions on ClearCase because you always get an answer ;) Thank you very much, I will try it ASAP

Comment: @andymeissner Did you make it work? What kind of script did you write?

Comment: In this case, I only wondered how to do this using CLI, because else I looked up the Integrationsstream in the CC-Explorer. Maybe for future usage ^^

Comment: Generally I'm learning CC, because I have to update (and maintain from dev side), then restructure it for performance and in the long term replace it with git and tooling

Comment: So to conclude I'm writing multiple scripts for measuring performance, checking stuff etc.

Comment: And yes it did work I only had to add the 'project'-modifier like this: `cleartool descr -fmt "%[istream]Xp" project:MyProject@\myPVob`

Comment: @andymeissner Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you CD or set into your view, cleartool lsstream -long -cview should tell you your default deliver target, which is *usually* the integration stream. If it's not, you can get the information from the project listed or by looking at the default deliver target...

Comment: This works too, it shows a summary of the stream and the default deliver stream is the one I was searching for